# Change background-color with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, colors, background

I want to change the global background-color for my app, but things don't work.

Adding CSS to the body doesn't work (neither does adding CSS to html element)

```
body {
    background-color:#2b2e31;
}
```

Adding id's to my div-elements works sometimes, but I'm not gonna add an Id to all my elements.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: (F12) Opening firebug or Developer Tools and inspecting your element

Comment: Got it! Appearantly .ui-page { 
    background:#2b2e31;
} solved it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: youre welcome! You can always remove the question.

Comment: please don't remove the question!  as it just helped me. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This solved it

```
.ui-page { 
    background:#2b2e31;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe this might work. Just download the 'Without-A-Theme' jQuery mobile CSS version.
Here is the link: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css
[image: You can find this in the jQuery mobile page]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the ui-page class. It may also be helpful to use **!important** so the rule will always be applied no matter where it appears in the CSS.

```
.ui-page {
  background-color: #2b2e31 !important;
}
```